# persist only the base class with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, inheritance

I’m having an inheritance mapping like Animal and Cat. Both classes have their own table (mapped as joined-subclass). I'm now trying that NHibernate saves only an Animal object, when I supply a Cat object to NHibernate's save (or persist) method.

From reading the documentation I assumed that `session.Save("Animal", catObject)` should do what I want, but it behaves exactly like `session.Save(catObject)`.

However, creating a new Animal object and copying the values from the Cat object works, but that would be a waste of time and memory.

Is there any other possibility to achieve what I want?

Comment: This smells wrong as a design. But I think you're prematurely optimizing: creating an Animal from a Cat is insignificant in both time and memory compared to the overhead from using NHibernate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, and IMO if you need to then you have a design problem. If you need to save an `Animal` then you must work with an `Animal` instance, not a `Cat` or whatever other type instance

Also as @PaulPhillips says the performance/memory cost of creating one object is in must of the cases negligible

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is clearly a design problem, but as often the code is there, unchangeable (due high costs) and you have to work with it.

Comment: I understand that, anyway if you can create an Animal instance and copy the Cat values to it, as you say in your question, that would solve your problem and it is not a waste of time and memory, it is completely negligible.